# Что значит "тип ^ переменная;"? (CLR)

Tags: c++-cli

В среде CLR (формы .NET, но на c++) меня ввели в ступор переменные следующего вида:

```
System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
```

Что тут значит символ `^` после типа данных и перед названием переменной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это указатели на "управляемую память". То есть память, которая управляется .NET и выделяется через gcnew .

Называют они это Handle to Object Operator (^) - [прям на сайта MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160)

- https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/extensions/ref-new-gcnew-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160
- https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2017/05/07/%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-6-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-native-%D0%B8-managed-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B4/